# How to understand the following quotes of Edmund Burke?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Can anyone please shed some light on the following quotes of Edmund Burke?

> Society cannot exist unless a controlling power upon will and appetite be placed somewhere, and **the less of it there is within, the more there must be without**. It is ordained in the eternal constitution of things, that men of intemperate minds cannot be free.

The part I fail to apprehend is bold-faced. I guess "it" in that part refers to the "controlling power". But then what does "there is within" mean? Also "there must be without" *what*?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Warning. This is not standard modern English.  Why are you learning English using this sort of text?

Comment: See  definition of adverb **without** here: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/without

Answer (score 2):

The less we are able to control ourselves (within us), the more external power should there be (without=outside us) to control ourselves.